# Advice on Building a Portable foley stage/pit

Tags: foley, post-production, production, diy, foley-stage

I'm starting prep on building a portable, decent sounding, foley stage/pit. I'm not yet based in a space,just a home studio, so the design needs to be something that can be folded away and/or renting to people.

I'm asking help on where to start really? And if this is possible. What wood material is best? Best methods to damp sound? Measurements? etc.

This is completely out of my depth so I'm learning from scratch but its exciting.

Answer (score 1):

Foley 'pits' are usually used for the footsteps part of the foley process. Consequently each 'pit' will contain a different 'surface' to be used for footsteps. Unfortunately some surfaces will be denser and heavier than others which may lead to some practical issues when trying to make this 'portable'.

It might be possible to build some wooden 'pits' and then store these away for use when a particular surface is required.

Some foley studios build pits with a cover so that the pits are 'temporary' and covered with a floor surface when not in use.

I think mass/weight and portability is going to be your biggest challenge with this.